# Can not get the list object from NotifyCollectionChangedeventargs in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have use the following code snippet in our working scenorio

```
 List<Data> list =new List<Data>();
        list.Add(new Data(){No = 1,Name = "Raja"});
        list.Add(new Data() { No = 2, Name = "Rajesh" });
        var data = list[0];
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args =new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove,list,1);
        var temp = args.OldItems[0];
```

I cannot get the list[0] from args and it is working fine in WPF . Can you please any look  into this and please provide guidance to achieve my requirement. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653211.aspx) constructor that populates the `OldItems` field.  You are currently using the [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653208.aspx) constructor that populates the changed item and index, which corresponds to the `NewItems` property

**Edit:** Just noticed you tagged silverlight.  It does not appear to have that constructor, so you could create it yourself, otherwise I'm not sure how you could get around it since it will pass it as an object (your code would then have to look like this: `var temp = ((IList)args.OldItems[0])[0];` to get the same result as with the WPF version).

Comment: Thank you for your reply .Yes ,I need to populate OldItem fields

Comment: Ok Thank you .But in our requirment we need to get the object from 0th index in OldItems .How to get this ? I have tried to case args.OldItems to List object .But i can cast this. Can you pleasae provide suggestion to me for how to get the oth object from e.OldItems  . In provided code snippet i need to get the list[0] from e.OldItems . It is possible?